# Timer not updating event after second iteration

Tags: c#, timer, timeout

I am using a timer -

```
static int count = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // set time
        timer1.Interval = System.Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) * 1000;
        // start timer
        timer1.Enabled = true;

        // set iterations
        count = System.Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);

    }
```

Where the tick is -

```
private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count--;
        if (count == 0)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;

        }
        listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text + " : " + count.ToString());

        var status = textBox1.Text + " : " + count.ToString();
        }
```

When I set the time to tick every one second, and the count to 4, I presumed that this would run the event every second, and repeat it 4 times. However once it repeats the event three times, it crashes.
The list box gets updated with -

```
test : 3
test : 2
test : 1
```

The error is -

```
The operation has timed out
```

I believe this might be due to the fact that I am making a webrequest within the timer tick - `

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resource_url);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            byte[] content = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postBody);
            stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
        }
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();`
```

How can I get round this issue? As further reading has shown that this error comes up when making more than 2 calls to a URL.

Comment: I wasn't able to duplicate the issue. What version of the framework are you using? What Timer are you using (Forms.Timer or Timers.Timer)? Is there something else trying to access the timer on the form? The fact that I can't replicate the issue suggests that there's something else being done that we aren't being told about.

Comment: Yes you are correct, within the timer tick, I am doing an HttpWebRequest I have added the code where I am doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add -

```
response.Close();
```

After the line -

```
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `timer1.Stop()` instead of `timer1.Enabled = false;`

```
if (count == 0)
{
   timer1.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't resolve the problem unfortunately. Still the same error message, i'm thinking it may be an off by one error.